# Wrong charset using Gios.Word.WordDocument in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

I have inherited ASP.NET project, which is generating some word documents using Gios.Word.WordDocument.

My problem is, everything works fine on my computer, with czech locale, but on english version server some diacritics are missing. I have no experiences with this library, so I don't know where to start.

Basically it works like this:

```
Gios.Word.WordDocument rd = new WordDocument(WordDocumentFormat.A4);

Font fontRegular = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
rd.SetFont(fontRegular);

var rt = rd.NewTable(fontRegular, Color.Black, rows, 2, 10);
WordCell title = rt.Rows[0][0];

title.SetFont(fontRegular);
title.Write("dle vzoru přílohy č. 2 Nařízení vlády č. 201/2010Sb.");

rd.SaveToFile("/* path to file */");
```

The bad result on the server looks like this `dle vzoru prílohy c. 1 Narízení vlády c. 201/2010Sb.`

I have tried to set up font this way:

```
Font fontBold = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point, 238); // 238 eastern europe charset byte
```

But no chage is happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have modified this library to generate RTF in unicode. Modified version source is published on:

https://github.com/FandaCZ/Gios.Word